# Django, how to know the exact type of child's class (if possible)

Tags: python, django, django-models

this is my models.py

```
class UserWidget(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="widgets")
    widget = models.ForeignKey(Widget)
    options = JSONField(default="{}")
    category = models.ManyToManyField(WidgetUserCategory)

class UserWidgetAtomic(UserWidget):
    atomic = models.ForeignKey(Atomic)

class UserWidgetNonAtomic(UserWidget):
    nonatomic = models.ForeignKey(NonAtomic)
```

On my views.py I do this:

```
widgets = category.userwidget_set.all()
```

or this (it doesn't matter)

```
widgets = user.widgets.all()
```

I would like to know (if possible) while iterating the type of the subclassed object.

for example

```
for item in widgets:
    if item.__class__.__name__ == "UserWidgetAtomic":
        do this
    elif item.__class__.__name__ == "UserWidgetNonAtomic":
        do that
```

Is this possible? How?

Comment: Somthing like `if isinstance(item, UserWidgetAtomic): ...` https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance

Comment: Yes, but this does not work. While isinstance(item, UserWidget) gives me True, isinstance(item, UserWidgetAtomic) gives me False

Comment: I think you table structure is overly complicated. It seems to me, that the `UserWidget` should be used as an intermediate many2many model. Could you add your `Atomic` and `NonAtomic` model to your question? Also `category` seems to be misplaced on the `UserWidget` model. It's a many2many relation so it's name should be `categories`.

Answer (score 0):

The need to do this is probably the result of an unsuitable table structure.

My first impression is that `UserWidget` is the relation between a `User` and a `Widget`. The obvious sign for this is, that it has foreign keys to both. It is probably better to define that model as an [itermediate many2many model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).

Additionally the field `category` seems to be misplaced. Since it is a many2many relation it's name should always be something like `categories`. 
Probably it's just a foreign key on the `Widget` model. Then `category` would make sense.

Also you created 2 subclasses of `UserWidget`. This introduces some difficulties with handling them. If all your user widgets are of the type `UserWidgetAtomic` or `UserWidgetNonAtomic` you should make your `UserWidget` model abstract. You should double check if [multi-table-inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) is really nessecary in your case because it can make things much more complicated.